# imprimir en pantalla sin repiticiones con un contenedor) python

Tags: python, contenedores

La consigna es la siguiente:
Realizar la carga de la información de las mascotas en un diccionario, ingresando su
nombre y los datos solicitados, en caso de ingresar un nombre que ya existe, el programa
debe informar esta situación y volver a pedir otro nombre, finalizando cuando ingresa el
nombre de mascota ‘FIN’
Imprimir en pantalla los diferentes tipos de animales registrados, sin repeticiones. Para
resolverlo hacer uso de otro contenedor que no admita repetidos. Esto debe resolverse
en una función.

Lo que me falta es el segundo punto.

tengo esto:

```
dic = {"NombreMascota":[]  ,
       "Tipo":[] ,
       "Edad":[] ,
       "Direccion":[]  ,
       "Dueño":[], } 

def cargaDatos():

nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: ")
tipo = input("¿Que animal es? ")
edad = int(input("Ingrese la edad de la mascota: "))
direccion = input("Ingrese la direccion de su casa: ")
dueño = input("Ingrese su nombre(dueño): ")

while nombre != "FIN":
    dic["NombreMascota"].append(nombre)
    dic["Tipo"].append(tipo)
    dic["Edad"].append(edad)
    dic["Direccion"].append(direccion)
    dic["Dueño"].append(dueño)
    
    nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: ")
    tipo = input("¿Que animal es? ")
    edad = int(input("Ingrese la edad de la mascota: "))
    direccion = input("Ingrese la direccion de su casa: ")
    dueño = input("Ingrese su nombre(dueño): ")

    if nombre in dic["NombreMascota"]:
        print("Ya existe una mascota con este nombre")
        nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: ")
        dic["NombreMascota"].append(nombre)
```

y la funcion que no puedo realizar:

```
def imprim(listaMasc):   
mens = "Los animales registrados son: "
conj = set()
for i in dic:
    if (dic["Tipo"][0] not in conj):
        conj.add(dic["Tipo"][0])
        mens += conj 
return mens`
```

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso, suponiendo que tienes todo implementado dentro del mismo archivo solo bastaria con hacer lo siguiente:

```
conj = set()
for i in dic["Tipo"]:
        conj.add(i)

print(conj)
```

Recuerda que el **set** no admite duplicados, por lo tanto no necesitas validar con un if.

Answer (score 0):

El código se puede mejorar, partiendo por la representación de los datos. Dado que guardas información sobre animales, identificados por su nombre, lo más natural es tener un diccionario indexado por nombre cuyo valor sea otro diccionario que contenga los datos de ese animal. O sea, en lugar de

```
dic = {"NombreMascota":[]  ,
       "Tipo":[] ,
       "Edad":[] ,
       "Direccion":[]  ,
       "Dueño":[], }
```

tenemos

```
dic["pillin"] = {"Tipo": "perro", "Edad": 5, "Direccion": "La Paz 23", "Dueño": "Raul Gomez"}
```

Con esto el código se reduce considerablemente:

```
dic = {}

def cargaDatos():

    while True:
        nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: ")
        if nombre == "FIN":
            break
        elif nombre in dic:
            print("Ya existe una mascota con este nombre")
        else:
            atributos = {}

            atributos["Tipo"] = input("¿Que animal es? ")
            atributos["Edad"] = int(input("Ingrese la edad de la mascota: "))
            atributos["Direccion"] = input("Ingrese la direccion de su casa: ")
            atributos["Dueño"] = input("Ingrese su nombre(dueño): ")

            dic[nombre] = atributos
```

Para listar en forma única los tipos de animal, usaremos una simple lista. EN ella iremos anotando los tipos a medida que los imprimimos. Antes de imprimir preguntamos si el tipo ya está en la lista:

```
lista = []
for atributos in dic.values():
    tipo = atributos["Tipo"]
    if tipo not in lista:
        print(tipo)
        lista.append(tipo)
```

#### Demo

```
dic = {}
def cargaDatos():

    while True:
        nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: ")
        if nombre == "FIN":
            break
        elif nombre in dic:
            print("Ya existe una mascota con este nombre")
        else:
            atributos = {}

            atributos["Tipo"] = input("¿Que animal es? ")
            atributos["Edad"] = int(input("Ingrese la edad de la mascota: "))
            atributos["Direccion"] = input("Ingrese la direccion de su casa: ")
            atributos["Dueño"] = input("Ingrese su nombre(dueño): ")

            dic[nombre] = atributos

cargaDatos()
lista = []
for atributos in dic.values():
    tipo = atributos["Tipo"]
    if tipo not in lista:
        print(tipo)
        lista.append(tipo)
```

produce:

```
Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: oso
¿Que animal es? gato
Ingrese la edad de la mascota: 1
Ingrese la direccion de su casa: asdf
Ingrese su nombre(dueño): a
Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: pillin
¿Que animal es? gato
Ingrese la edad de la mascota: 1
Ingrese la direccion de su casa: 12
Ingrese su nombre(dueño): 3
Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: add
¿Que animal es? canario
Ingrese la edad de la mascota: 2
Ingrese la direccion de su casa: 3
Ingrese su nombre(dueño): 34
Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: FIN
gato
canario

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

La estructura de datos la puedes crear de dos formas, un **diccionario de listas** o un **diccionario de diccionarios**.

**diccionario de listas:**

```
    #   orden_de_lista_de_datos = [tipo, edad]
    #   dicc_de_mascotas = {'Nombre de mascota':[tipo, edad]}
    dicc_de_mascotas = {'Gatito': [ 'gato',  5],
                        'Leo': ['leon', 2],
                        'Micki': ['raton', 3],
                        'Gatin': [ 'gato', 1]
                        }
```

**diccionario de diccionarios:**

```
    #   dicc_de_mascotas = {'Nombre de mascota': {'Tipo': 't1', 'Edad': 1} }

    dicc_de_mascotas = {'Gatito': {'Tipo': 'gato', 'Edad': 5},
                    'Leo': {'Tipo': 'leon', 'Edad': 2},
                    'Micki': {'Tipo': 'raton', 'Edad': 3},
                    'Gatin': {'Tipo': 'gato', 'Edad': 1}
                    }
```

**Con diccionario de diccionarios:**

```
def carga_datos(dicc_de_mascotas:dict):

    while True:

        nombre = input('Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: ')
        if nombre.upper() == 'FIN': break
        if nombre in dicc_de_mascotas or nombre == '':
            print('No es un nombre válido')
            continue
            
        mascota = {
            'Tipo': input('¿Que animal es? '),
            'Edad': int(input('Ingrese la edad de la mascota: ')),
            'Direccion': input('Ingrese la direccion de su casa: '),
            'Dueño': input('Ingrese su nombre(dueño): ')
        }
        dicc_de_mascotas[nombre] = mascota

    print('Acabó la carga de datos')
    return dicc_de_mascotas

dic = {}
dic = carga_datos(dic)
```

Para mostrar los tipos en una función:

Primero crear un `set` con los valores `tipo` únicos

```
def mostrar_tipos(dicc_de_mascotas:dict):
    lista_de_tipos = set() 
    for dato in dicc_de_mascotas.values():
        lista_de_tipos.add(dato['Tipo'])
```

que por *comprension de listas* también puede ser:

```
def mostrar_tipos(dicc_de_mascotas:dict):
    lista_de_tipos = { dato['Tipo'] for dato in dicc_de_mascotas.values() }
```

Después para imprimirlos recorrer la función e ir imprimiendo.

```
def mostrar_tipos(dicc_de_mascotas:dict):
    lista_de_tipos = { dato['Tipo'] for dato in dicc_de_mascotas.values() }
    print('Tipos de mascotas: ')
    print(', '.join(lista_de_tipos))
```

Si no necesitas dar formato a la impresión: `print(*lista de tipos)`

**El código completo:**

```
def carga_datos(dicc_de_mascotas:dict):
    while True:
        nombre = input('Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: ')
        if nombre.upper() == 'FIN': break
        if nombre in dicc_de_mascotas or nombre == '':
            print('No es un nombre válido')
            continue  # Salto al inicio del bucle

        mascota = {
            'Tipo': input('¿Que animal es? '),
            'Edad': int(input('Ingrese la edad de la mascota: ')),
            'Direccion': input('Ingrese la direccion de su casa: '),
            'Dueño': input('Ingrese su nombre(dueño): ')
        }
        dicc_de_mascotas[nombre] = mascota

    print('Acabó la carga de datos')
    return dicc_de_mascotas

def mostrar_tipos(dicc_de_mascotas:dict):
    lista_de_tipos = { dato['Tipo'] for dato in dicc_de_mascotas.values() }
    print('Tipos de mascotas: ')
    print(', '.join(lista_de_tipos))




dic = {}
dic = carga_datos(dic)
mostrar_tipos(dic)
```

**Con diccionario de listas:**

```
def carga_datos(dicc_de_mascotas:dict):
    while True:
        nombre = input('Ingrese el nombre de la mascota: ')
        if nombre.upper() == 'FIN': break
        if nombre in dicc_de_mascotas or nombre == '':
            print('No es un nombre válido')
            continue

        #   orden_de_lista_de_datos = ['tipo', 'edad', 'Direccion', 'Dueño' ]
        #   dicc_de_mascotas = {'Nombre de mascota': [tipo, edad, Direccion, Dueño ] }

        dicc_de_mascotas[nombre] = []
        dicc_de_mascotas[nombre].append(input('¿Que animal es? ') )
        dicc_de_mascotas[nombre].append(int(input('Ingrese la edad de la mascota: ') ) )
        dicc_de_mascotas[nombre].append(input('Ingrese la direccion de su casa: ') )
        dicc_de_mascotas[nombre].append(input("Ingrese su nombre(dueño): ") )

    print('Acabó la carga de datos')
    return dicc_de_mascotas

def mostrar_tipos(dicc_de_mascotas:dict):
    print('Tipos de mascotas: ')
    lista_de_tipos = { dato[0] for dato in dicc_de_mascotas.values() }  #   Set
    print( ', '.join(lista_de_tipos) )


dic = {}
dic = carga_datos(dic)
mostrar_tipos(dic)
```

.